# Colspan not working in angular 6

Tags: angular, html-table, angular6

I have a table as follow:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
// five columns in the table head
        <th colspan="3">ARTICLES</th>
        <th colspan="1">CLS/CRT</th>
        <th colspan="1">PIECE</th>
        <th colspan="1">prix par pièce</th>
        <th colspan="2">NOTES</th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" matInput placeholder="Article" >
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <input placeholder="Montant" type="number">
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <input placeholder="PIECE" type="number">
        </td>
        <td colspan="1">
            <input matInput placeholder="prix par pièce" type="number">
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
            <input placeholder="Écrivez Une note ici..">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have used angularJS to create web app before but I'm new to Angular 6.  I'm facing the above problem and I couldn't find any solutions via searching stack overflow that helped me.

Comment: `colspan` is used to merge columns, not to size them.

Comment: @trichetriche Colspan is used to merge columns? does't that mean it makes one column equal to two columns if `colspan` set equal 2?

Comment: That's exactly it. But it doesn't mean the column is taking twice the width : it means the column is made of two columns. Colspans are based on the table headers : if you have 5 header cells, like you do, then the total sum of the colspans must be equal to 5. Here, you are above it (3+1+1+1+2 = 8).

Comment: (and colspans are not to be used in header cells)

Comment: @trichetriche still not working, i think this because of angular 6 have not declare `colspan` as native attribute oh html, any thoughts ?

Comment: `[attr.colspan]`, and be more specific about "Not working"